# java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException while implementing Producer-Consumer in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to implement the Producer consumer problem in Java. I am trying to implement a functionality where a Producer pushes an item to the stack and waits for the consumer to consume it. The consumer waits for the stack to have some values before it tries to consume it.

This should happen in an infinite loop. The problem is that the code runs only once and then I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at com.nik.threads.Producer.run(Producer.java:28)
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at com.nik.threads.Consumer.run(Consumer.java:28)
```

The problem is with the `notify()` call. I know that the issue is occurring as the thread doesn't know whom to notify as it isn't aware of the waiting threads. But I am unable to implement it. Below is my code:

Producer.java:

```
class Producer extends Thread{
    private Stack<Integer> stack;
    public Producer(Stack<Integer> stack){
        this.stack=stack;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0;;i++){
            if(!stack.isEmpty())
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        stack.push(i);
        try {
            sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        notify();
    }   }
}
```

Consumer.java:

```
 class Consumer extends Thread{
        private Stack<Integer> stack;

        public Consumer(Stack<Integer> stack){
            this.stack=stack;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(;;){
                if(stack.isEmpty())
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                System.out.println("Consumed:"+stack.pop());
                try {
                    sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

ProducerConsumer.java:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class ProducerConsumer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Stack<Integer> stack=new Stack<>();
        Producer p=new Producer(stack);
        Consumer c=new Consumer(stack);
        p.start();
        c.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to synchronize on the monitor you call wait and notify on

```
synchronized(this) wait();
```

and

```
synchronized(this) notify();
```

(in your case)

(and there also a number of other issues, like, always check wait conditions in loops and use a dedicated monitor object, not this to wait and notify on, and use notifyAll instead of notify)